# Describe how a php page template can write another php page as html

Tags: php

Describe the mechanics in PHP relevant terms of a PHP/MYSQL page (A.php) that will 1) use one template to write itself (simple), 2) take input from the user to update a database (simple), 3) upon command parse another PHP page (B.php) (???) and save (B.php) page as a static HTML (B.html) (???).

UPDATE= I found a post, here at SO, helpfully suggesting (to another, GROAN, non-Uber Geek with a completely Pedestrian Question) he could capture html from a php page using output buffer. Will this work for a different php file?

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: Yes, The International School of OpenSource, BABY! No Question is too dumb. Only dumb answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It saddened me to get reamed on this question. To show my Q was in good faith, I'm answering my own question with what was a simple solution. I created generate.php to run when a change was made to the content. No cache needed.

```
// the switch...
$update_live = isset($_GET['update_live']) ? TRUE : FALSE;
// $adminPath, $livePath, $adminUrl are set in an include and contains site config data...
$tempfile = $adminPath . 'tempindex.html'; //a temp file...
$livefile = $livePath . 'index.html'; //the static live file...
$this_template = $adminUrl . 'main-index.php'; //the php template file...
$username = "php_admin";
$password = "123xyz456";

if(!($update_live)){
        $errors[] = "Did not submit from an edit page. You can only access this page by referral!";
}else{
        if(file_exists($tempfile)){
                unlink($tempfile);
        }
        /* =3, $html = file_get_contents($this_template, false, $context);*/
        $html = file_get_contents($this_template);
        if($html === false){
                $errors[] = "Unable to load template. Static page update aborted!";
                exit();
        }
        if(!file_put_contents($tempfile, $html)){
                $errors[] = "Unable to write $tempfile. Static page update aborted!";
                exit();
        }

        if(!copy($tempfile, $livefile)){
                $errors[] = "Unable to overwrite index file. Static page update aborted!";
                exit();
        }
        if(!unlink($tempfile)){
                $errors[] = "Unable to delete $tempfile. Static page update aborted!";
                exit();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more complex and better answers to each question, but I'm going to jot down the most simple ones.

1. PHP is a template language, so a PHP file with your template is your answer. This question is a bit vague.
2. Access the user-provided data using the $_GET or $_POST superglobals, with the choice depending on your HTTP request method. Basically, GET is for URL data, POST for form data. Once you have the data, validate it. Then use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) to connect to a database and execute an insertion query.
3. You can use an output buffer, like so:

   `ob_start(); // Start output buffer
   require 'B.php'; // Execute B.php, storing its output to the buffer
   file_put_contents('B.html', ob_get_clean()); // Clean the buffer, retrieve its contents and write them to B.html`

Comment: I tried to consider the possibility of this being homework when writing my answer. I hope the answer will be informative enough to get someone with honest intentions on the right track.

Comment: 2) HAHAH. Ok. I see what you mean about vague. I didn't mean, "What is PHP and what can it do for me". I'm already programming in PHP 3) That's it! Thanks!
Now, I'm going to upset someone again, but imagine for a moment you ran into a problem that needed this output buffer solution, how do you describe PHP using another PHP page? 
EX. If you use PHP include function in an HTML page, you can modularize the chunks of the HTML page. So I might search or use terms to describe this as modular, chunks, "php html template".

Again. I'm sorry, I just couldn't think how to describe my question.

Comment: Anyone want to click my question back up? It hurts my self esteem. :(

Comment: PSS. Check out my previous question here that never got op_buffer(),
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409483/php-page-caching-solution-suggestions-for-cms-applications
And another at PHPfreaks,
http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php/topic,306667.msg1450889.html#msg1450889